# css how to make this checkbox smaller

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want to put in it a customer checkboxes.

The div is the red one.

Please check the attached image. the checkboxes go out of the red area thought I made the `overflow` as auto.

how to make the checkboxes smaller please?

[image]

Please how to make the checkboxes smaller

Comment: You want the check box smaller or want the div to cover them all?

Comment: @TejasPatel I want them smaller and I also would like if the div has scroll when it can't cover them all. I hope you got me, me english is poor

Comment: @TejasPatel I mean they are too large, did u got me idea pleae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction in your HTML. You had same ID on input and same reference `for` attribute in label which will more likely not work.
Updated HTML:

```
<div ID="campaignDiv" runat="server">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" />
            <label for="1"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="1" />
            <label for="2"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="1" />
            <label for="3"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="1" />
            <label for="4"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For reducing the size, just play around with `top,left,height,width,font-size` property:

```
#campaignDiv {
    background-color: red;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;    
}
#campaignDiv ul {
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;    
}
#campaignDiv input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#campaignDiv input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 60px;
    background: #26ca28;
}
#campaignDiv li {
    width: 120px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 10px 30px;//Changed
    border-radius: 30px;//Changed
    position: relative;
}
#campaignDiv li:before {
    content:'On';
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;//Changed
    left: 13px;
    height: 2px;
    color: #26ca28;
    font-size: 12px;//Changed
}
#campaignDiv li:after {
    content:'Off';
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;//Changed
    left: 84px;
    height: 2px;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 12px;//Changed
}
#campaignDiv li label {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;//Changed
    height: 14px;//Changed
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;//Changed
    z-index: 1;
    left: 12px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

You can compare the CSS with your css to know the changes done in the code.

Comment: many thanks, could u please remove the jsfille link. thanks for understanding

Comment: Okay, removed that link.